# My update function is not working while updating database

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code in my update function in Company Model but it does not update data base?

```
public function update(Request $request, Company $company)
    { 
        $companyupdate = Company::where('id', $company->id)->update([
                                           'name'=>$request->input('name'),
                                           'description'=>$request->input('description') 
                                        ]);
        if($companyupdate){ 
            return redirect()->route('companies.show',['company'=>$company->id])
                         ->with('success','Company Updated Successfully');
        } 


        return back()->withInput();
    }
```

And the below is my view code that contains form, which sends record to update function.But it is not updating the record in database. Anyone knows what the problem is..??where did i make a mistake in the code

`````
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
   <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-9 pull-left">
   <!-- Jumbotron -->

       <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="background-color:white; margin:10px;">
           <form mehtod="post" action="{{ route('companies.update', [$company->id]) }}">
               {{ csrf_field() }}
               <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">

               <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="company-name">Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                   <input placeholder="Enter Name"
                       id="company-name"
                       required
                       name="name"
                       spellcheck="false"
                       class="form-control"
                       value="{{$company->name}}"
                   />
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="company-content">Description</label>
                   <textarea placeholder="Enter Description"
                       id="company-content"
                       required
                       name="description"
                       spellcheck="false"
                       class="form-control autosize-target text-left"
                       rows="5"> 
                       {{ $company->description }}</textarea>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
               </div>
           </form>
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 pull-right">
        <!-- <div class="sidebar-module sidebar-module-inset">
       <h4>About</h4>
           <p>Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
         </div>-->
         <div class="sidebar-module">
           <h4>Actions</h4>
           <ol class="list-unstyled">
             <li><a href="/companies/{{ $company->id }}">View Company</a></li>
             <li><a href="/companies">All Companies</a></li>
           </ol>
         </div>
         <!--<div class="sidebar-module">
           <h4>Members</h4>
           <ol class="list-unstyled">
             <li><a href="#">March 2014</a></li>
           </ol>
         </div>-->
   </div>
   @endsection

````
`````

Comment: How is it not working? Include an error if possible.

Comment: It's not giving any kind of error also

Comment: Can you run `dd($companyupdate);` after update query and give us the result?

Comment: its not working, i think the update function is not running at all

Comment: because i tried to put $company in dd() but it did not run....and directly goes to show view without any updation being made....